# Maven 3.3.3 - MAC Yosemite - Error: Could not find or load main class when trying to run mvn -version

Tags: java, maven

i have the following in my .bash_profile

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This is a direct copy and paste from terminal

```
Last login: Mon May 25 20:58:46 on ttys000
Harleys-MacBook-Pro:~ chiphansel$ open .bash_profile
Harleys-MacBook-Pro:~ chiphansel$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
Harleys-MacBook-Pro:~ chiphansel$ mvn -version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
Harleys-MacBook-Pro:~ chiphansel$ echo $PATH
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
Harleys-MacBook-Pro:~ chiphansel$
```

It finds java is set up correctly (I think) and maven is the correct directory. I am new to Mac and I am finding my lack of knowledge very frustrating.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Mac world! Looks like you're using `Homebrew`. If yes, you don't need to export `$M2_HOME` and `$M2`. But your `Homebrew` cellars should be added to  `$PATH` correctly.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

`/usr/local/bin` is everything `Homebrew` needs.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And try to remove the `/jre` at the end of your `$JAVA_HOME`.

Please don't add `$JAVA_HOME` to `$PATH`.